# How to conditionally display form elements with jQuery based on user choices

Tags: jquery, webforms

I'm developing a web form for a client which is pretty straightforward, but there are places where they want sub-options to appear based on the user's choice.

Simple logic:

```
if user chooses this,
    display these sub-options, 
if other choice > these sub-options, 
if another choice > other sub-options
```

So I'll give an example.  There is a select box where users choose a "finished type" for their order quote. There are 10 options in this box, 6 of them have multiple sub-options (mostly Y/N radio buttons, but some have text input, or another select box), and some of them have deeper levels of sub-options that can display depending on what the user is choosing.

I have the groups of sub-options inside a `<div>` which is hidden by default.

When a user chooses the corresponding option from the select box, the corresponding div of sub-options should `.slideDown()`.   When something else is chosen, it will `.slideUp()`.

Here's what I have so far (which is obviously incomplete) - more description below the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#finished_types").change(function() {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "Saddle Stitching" :
                $("#saddle_stitching").slideDown("fast");
                break;

            case "Loose Leaf / 4 Side Trim" :
                break;

            case "Perfect Binding" :
                break;

            case "Wire-O" :
                break;

            case "Plastic Coil" :
                break;

            case "Collating Only" :
                break;

            case "Folding Only" :
                break;

            case "Corner Stitching" :
                break;

            case "Side Stitching" :
                break;

            default:
                $("#saddle_stitching").slideUp("fast");
                $("#loose_leaf").slideUp("fast");
                $("#perfect_binding").slideUp("fast");
                $("#wire_o").slideUp("fast");
                $("#plastic_coil").slideUp("fast");
                $("#collating_only").slideUp("fast");
                $("#folding_only").slideUp("fast");
                $("#corner_stitching").slideUp("fast");
                $("#side_stitching").slideUp("fast");
        }
    }).change();        
});
```

The tricky part for me is that I also want ALL sub-option fields to be reset/cleared if the user chooses a different Finished Type from the select box (basically anytime they're hidden).  I feel like there should be a way to do this by calling another function or more, instead of coding it into each switch case and making everything much larger than it needs to be.

Also, is there any difference in coding the lower levels of sub-options, or would it be pretty much the same?

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to read through this big mess.  Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: The title "How to do complex magic with jQuery and HTML form elements" doesn't really give a relevant summary of the question, if you ask me.

Comment: I think you should look into [jQuery templates](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37898666/Template).

Answer (score 0):

Use classes.  So instead of having:

```
<div id="saddle_stitching">foo</div>
<div id="loose_leaf">bar</div>
<div id="perfect_binding">hello</div>
<div id="wire_o">world</div>
```

Try:

```
<div id="saddle_stitching" class="extra_option">foo</div>
<div id="loose_leaf" class="extra_option">bar</div>
<div id="perfect_binding" class="extra_option">hello</div>
<div id="wire_o" class="extra_option">world</div>
```

In this scenario, you could just do:

```
jQuery('.extra_option').slideUp('fast');
```

Instead of listing all the different `id`s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want all of the extra options to show at once.  Only options that apply to the selection in the dropdown box. In your solution there would be no need for html ids,  but I have to differentiate between groups of options, and only show 1 group at a time.

Comment: Negative. Leave the ids. Use the `id` to show an individual group. Use `class` to hide a bunch.